# left_join command warning messages

Tags: r, dplyr, left-join

I am using the function left join as follows

```
left_join(PTF_2105_06_07,LimitDATA, by = "ID_ISIN" )
```

I have two questions

1. first I can see that the formula worked because I see a new column in the output following the command in the "Console" Area. Unfortunately, I cannot see the new column when I use the command View (). What is going wrong? How can I see the new dataset with the "vertical lookup" results?
2. I get the following message at the end of the output in the Console area "[ reached 'max' / getOption("max.print") -- omitted 16990336 rows ]".
   What does it mean? It did not create the match for 16990336, or it just was not able to show the output for 16990336 ?

Comment: Remember to assign your merged your a dataframe to an object `mynewdf <- left_join(df1, df2)`, then use `View()` on the object with the merged data frame.

Comment: The output you're seeing regarding question #2 is just R saying it ran out of room in displaying all the data on the console. It has nothing to do with what it is actually doing.

Comment: Thanks you Phil!  Really useful!